# Algebraic Manipulation with Simultaneous Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find $a+b+c$, given that $x+y\neq -1$ and \begin{align*}
ax+by+c&=x+7,\\
a+bx+cy&=2x+6y,\\
ay+b+cx&=4x+y.
\end{align*}

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Random hint: $\;1+2+4=6+1=7\,$. But really, you should add some context, and show what you have tried. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the three equations altogether to get:

$(ax+by+c)+(a+bx+cy)+(ay+b+cx)=(ax+bx+cx)+(ay+by+cy)+(a+b+c)= (a+b+c)(x+y+1)=7x+7y+7$

Since $x+y$ is not equal to $-1$, we can divide both sides of the equation by $x+y+1$ to get $a+b+c=(7x+7y+7)/(x+y+1)=7$ which gives us what we wanted.